# getting blank name (display name) from google plus api

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I am working on login system where user is logged to website using google plus api . I am hitting "me" endpoint after token verification .But I am facing a problem in some cases where I don't get the displayName/Name object of the user .
scopes used : plus.profile and plus.login 
Endpint hit : "me"

```
$service=new Google_Service_Plus($client);
    $userinfo=$service->people->get('me');
```

I want to fetch the username of the user .

Comment: Is it consistent with specific users? Can you replicate it with the [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get)? Are you sure you are not getting some error with the request that you are not catching?

Comment: @abraham: Yes , I am not even getting the result in API explorer . Problem is that i am getting displayName for some accounts and not for others . Is there any way to compel user for making a google plus account if he already do not have one .

Comment: I am getting blank names for those who are not google plus users . Is there any way to ask user to make a google plus account before signing into the application .

Comment: What `scopes` are you asking for during the sign-in flow?

Comment: I am using plus.email and plus.profile scopes .
I think I need to use deprecated userinfo.email and userinfo.profile scopes in order to compel user to make a new google plus profile if his gmail account is not linked to google plus account .

Comment: If found the docs that specify when a G+ account is required and added an answer. You also shouldn't use deprecated scopes.

Answer (score 1):

> Google+ Sign-In provides support for all users with a Google account, even if they have not yet created a Google+ profile. Your app can either prompt those users to create a Google+ profile (by using the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login scope) or not (by using the profile scope)

[Switch to Google+ Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#sign-in)

If you use the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` scope, users are guaranteed to have a Google+ profile.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to bring information about the **profile (Names) and Email**.

I'd recommed you add the follow scopes separated by two spaces:

```
profile  email
```

`profile` bring the Names (givenName, familyName, etc.) and `email` bring the email.